# Relations and functions.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

let $f:S\rightarrow T $ for non-empty sets $S$ and $T$ and let $C$ be a partition of $S$. Define a relation ~ on the set $T$ such that,

$t_1$ ~ $t_2$ if $\exists_{A\in C}$ : $f^{-1}( \{t_1,t_2 \} )$ $\subset$ A.

(a) Need ∼ be reflexive? What if f is injective?

(b) Need ∼ be symmetric? What if f is bijective?

(c) Need ∼ be transitive? What if f is surjective

I have only just discovered this site! Can't wait to contribute soon! Any ettiquette I may have broken please let me know. thanks People!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $f$ is not onto (surjective), then this relation on $T$ need not be reflexive. For example: Let $S=\{1,2,3\}$ with $C=\{\{1\}, \{2,3\}\}$ and let $T=\{a,b,c,d\}$. Define $f$ as 
$$f=\{(1,a), (2,b),(3,b)\}.$$
Then $c \not\sim c$ because $f^{-1}(\{c\}) = \phi.$ By the definition of partition, $\phi \not\subset C$.

Even if $f$ is injective, say
$$f=\{(1,a), (2,b),(3,c)\}.$$
then too $d \not\sim d$.

I hope this will help you approach the problem. In case you are unable to then please feel free to ask for more explanation.